# Excel doesn't load document by double-click

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I faced an issue when opening Excel document on my computer. Could anyone help to manage this?

- I am trying to open an Excel document in Windows by double-click. The
  Excel application opens, but doesn't load the document. So I see Excel GUI, nothing more.
- The document opens normally from Excel via the "File-Open" menu.
- Other Excel documents open normally on my computer by double-click.
- The document opens normally by double-click on another computer.
- I've never faced the problem before with this document on my computer.

I'd suppose that something is broken, but I guess my friends probably laughed at me and did something to my computer. What could it be?

Comment: Do you get any error pop up like open in `Safe Mode`? Also have you tried open an excel on web and from there, open the file on desktop mode? What error do you get, definitely you will need to repair `Excel` by uninstalling it or doing an online repair

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I see no error messages.

Comment: Ah ok, have you tried opening from web from there tried to open the same file on desktop option which says edit on desktop? While doing that does excel open on desktop mode?

Comment: Try repairing Excel.  Uninstall Office.  Restart the computer.  Install Office and update.   Test.

Comment: For the unlikely case of your friends messing with you: the implication is a macro which would mean a file extension of .xslm or .xslb. Since the file opens on other computers, I would rule this out. However, your friends could be even more devious and planted a personal.xslm file on your computer to cancel the open command for that file only.

Comment: @gns100 I suppose I'd see the macros in "View Macros" window?